# Psexec , cmd and batch file

Tags: scripting, cmd, psexec

I have a batch file named a.bat on a winserver2008 Desktop.

That batch file only write the SessionID (from environment variable) to a local eventlog.

I want to execute it remotely using cmd (otherwise the SessionName doesn't appear).

so I have tried

```
c:\PsTools\psexec.exe \\<Server> -u test2 -p <Password> -i 2 cmd "c:\Users\test-2\Desktop\a"
```

or

```
c:\PsTools\psexec.exe \\<server> -u test2 -p <Password> -i 2 "cmd \"c:\Users\test-2\Desktop\a\"";exit
```

all of these just open a terminal on the remote machine but don't execute the batch.

Any ides?

Best Regards,

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Use a /c on the command line after cmd.

So, your first line would look like:

```
c:\PsTools\psexec.exe \\<Server> -u test2 -p <Password> -i 2 cmd /c "c:\Users\test-2\Desktop\a"
```

Comment: I'll try that out
though my problem wasn't terminating the remote process but executng this command specific via cmd (and not "directly").

Answer (score 0):

`psexec \\<server> -s cmd.exe & whatever.bat`

If you're trying to run a batch remotely then when cmd is open on the remote through your terminal connection, you have two options:

1. `xcopy \\your_computer\filepath c:\wherever something.bat`
2. `run \\computername\c$\wherever_it_is_located`